# Misuse of dot-syntax for a convenient way to access an API in Python

Tags: python, namespaces, extract, getattr

I'd like to write an convenient interface for the `flickr-API` in `Python`. The methods provided by the API

```
flickr.galleries.addPhoto
flickr.galleries.create
flickr.cameras.getBrandModels
flickr.cameras.getBrands
etc.
```

are used in a normal http-request, like

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.X&param1=value1&param2=value2&param3&
```

My idea was to write a `class flickr`, which might enable me to call the methods in the same syntax in Python. So the class flickr, should enable me to access the identifier `X=galleries.addPhoto` when i call

```
flickr.X(param1=value1,param2=value2)
```

I thought about using the `getattr` function to use the function name as a parameter, but unfortunately i failed.

**Is there a way to access the name of X ignoring the dots.**

P.s. the `class flickr` should not check (or hold) the exact structure of the "namespaces" like galleries, camera, etc. to stay are generic as possible and not being affected as the names of methods will change in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I'd recommend stretching the python syntax so far but the **getattr** class method will work.  It is invoked whenever you access a member that is not in a class's dictionary, so you need to be sure that "X" is not a class member, use something like "_X" instead and then use a class structure like this:

```
class a(object):
    def _hi(self):
        print "hello"

    def __getattr__(self, val):
        a.__dict__["_" + val](self)

>>> b = a() 
>>> b.hi
hello
```

***EDIT: dealing with the dot syntax

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, call_tree=None):
        self.call_tree = call_tree

    def __getattr__(self, val):
        if self.call_tree:
            new_call_tree = '.'.join([self.call_tree, val])
        else:
            new_call_tree = val
        return A(call_tree=new_call_tree)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = 'https://api.flickr.com/?function={}'.format(self.call_tree)
        print url

>>> b = A()
>>> b.hi.mom()
https://api.flickr.com/?function=hi.mom
>>> b.hi.dad()
https://api.flickr.com/?function=hi.dad
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but: i am looking for a way, that do not need do rebuild the whole API structure given in the documentation. as there are a lost of lines of code to write, and the underlying API calls might change some day AND there a hidden methods (so the interface will allways be incomplete) so i thought: why not take a shortcut ; )

Comment: So the problem is overcoming the "." accessor?  That can be done though self-returning classes.  See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you experimented with flickr apis in python which already exist?

Here are couple:

- https://bitbucket.org/sybren/flickrapi/
- http://code.google.com/p/flickrpy/
- http://code.google.com/p/python-flickr-api/

At a minimum, you can checkout a copy of the code and get some ideas.

Comment: yes, i checked all of them. some of them are quiet handy, but they are very static, as they internally rebuilt the structure of the methods listed in the API documentation. For example: the interface located in 1) "https://bitbucket.org/sybren/flickrapi/" is replacing dots by "_" and using a dict to map all method calls. in 2) "http://code.google.com/p/flickrpy/" the class structure is rebuild in a python class, with the names have to exactly match the methods given in the API documentation. i would like to find a more dynamic way, with no need to rebuild a structure, which is not needed ...

Comment: ... the methods just passed as http request, so no need for a internal structure. but having the same syntax for calling the functions from python would be quiet nice.